# Is the char encoding same across programming languages?

Tags: java, python, c++, c, char

A very easy (and kind of elegant) way how to convert a lower-case letter-containing `char` into an `int` is to do the following:

```
int convertLowercaseCharLettertoInt(char letter) {
    return letter - 'a';
}
```

However, this code assumes that the `char` encoding follows the same ordering as the alphabet. Or, more generally, it assumes that `char` follows the ASCII encoding.

- I know that Java `char` is UTF-16 while C `char` is ASCII. Although UTF-16 is not backward-compatible with ASCII, the ordering of the first 128 letters is the same in both. **So is the ordering of the first 128 `char`s the same in all major languages such as C, C++, Java, C#, JavaScript and Python?**
- **Is the method above a safe thing to do in general (assuming the input is sanitized, etc.)?** Or is it better to use hash-map or long `switch` statement approaches? The hash-map approach is, I think, the most elegant way how to solve this problem in the case of non-English alphabets. E.g. the Czech alphabet goes: a, á, b, c, č, d, ď, e, é, ě, f, g, h, ch, i, í, j, k, l, m, n, ň, o, ó, p, q, r, ř, s, š, t, ť, u, ú, ů, v, w, x, y, ý, z, ž.

Comment: Encoding are defined by corresponding standards. ASCII, EBCDIC Unicode or you name it.

Comment: AFAIK, C# is similar to Java, JavaScript has a specified Unicode method `charCodeAt`, but in Python you can name any encoding you want.

Comment: In EBCDIC, the alphabet is not consequent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Comment: No, you cannot write a one function fits all, not even in `C++` where using different codepages is possible.

Comment: A main stream language *should* respect US-ASCII encoding. But obviously we cannot assume that from *all* languages. Some people might as well invent a language that rejects this indignant American imperialism!

Comment: @bayou.io People have invented such  languages ([Esperanto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto])) and computer ones [APL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)).  Yet in the free market of ideas, ASCII competitively is the  widely adopted choice made by many rather than by edict.

Comment: To be clear "C char is ASCII" mis-leads.  C does _not_ specify ASCII even though it is the dominate character encoding used for C code.  ASCII is prevalent in text files processed by C (though nor _required_).  UTF is certainly gaining ground in text files.

Answer (score 3):

This has less to do with programming language, but more about the system's underlying character set. ASCII and all variants of Unicode will behave as you expect. 'a'...'z' are 26 consecutive code points. EBCDIC will not, so your trick will fail on an IBM/360 in most languages.

Java (and Python, and perhaps other) languages mandate Unicode encoding regardless of the underlying platform, so your trick will work there as well, assuming you can find a conforming Java implementation for your IBM mainframe.

Comment: Java uses *a* Unicode encoding (UTF16) rather than just any 'Unicode encoding'

Comment: Yes, and 'a'..'z' are contiguous in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as C is concerned, you *cannot* rely on the execution character being ASCII; the standard only mandates the minimum set of characters that must belong to it.  The execution character set *may* be ASCII, it may be EBCDIC, it may be UTF-8, etc.

Your method is "safe" in the sense that it shouldn't cause a segfault or open a security hole, but it's not guaranteed to return the result you expect.

For the Latin alphabet, you'd be better off creating your own string and indexing into it:

```
char mycharset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
if ( isalpha( letter )) // thanks chux.
{
  char *pos = strchr( mycharset, tolower( letter ) );
  if ( pos )
    return (int) (pos - mycharset);
  else
    return -1; // letter not found
}
return -1; // bad input
```

For extended alphabets - I don't know.

Comment: Note this returns 26 should `letter == '\0'`  "The terminating null character is considered to be part of the string." `mycharset`.

Comment: @chux - Yeah, you'd want to add an `isalpha` check on `letter` before doing the search.  Good catch.

Comment: I was thinking a simple `if (letter)` would do.

Comment: @chux - or that.  Shouldn't work and surf at the same time (I'm *not* slacking, my code's compiling!)

Answer (score 1):

In C, the compiler could *detect* problems

```
#if 'a'+1=='b' && 'b'+1=='c' && 'c'+1=='d' && 'd'+1=='e' && 'e'+1=='f' \
  && 'f'+1=='g' && 'g'+1=='h' && 'h'+1=='i' && 'i'+1=='j' && 'j'+1=='k'\
  && 'k'+1=='l' && 'l'+1=='m' && 'm'+1=='n' && 'n'+1=='o' && 'o'+1=='p'\
  && 'p'+1=='q' && 'q'+1=='r' && 'r'+1=='s' && 's'+1=='t' && 't'+1=='u'\
  && 'u'+1=='v' && 'v'+1=='w' && 'w'+1=='x' && 'x'+1=='y' && 'y'+1=='z'

int convertLowercaseCharLettertoInt(char letter) {
  return letter - 'a';
}
#else
  int convertLowercaseCharLettertoInt(char letter) {
    static const char lowercase[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const char *occurrence = strchr(lowercase, letter);
    assert(letter && occurrence);
    return occurrence - lowercase;
  }
#endif
```

See also [@John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274871/2410359) code

---

Note: The following works in with all C encodings

```
int convertLowercaseOrUppercaseCharLettertoInt(char letter) {
  char s[2] = { letter, '\0' };
  return strtol(s, 0, 36) - 10;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you not use `tolower`?

Comment: @rici In an embedded application, the typical table used by `tolower()` cost 257 * 8 or 16 bits, plus other code.  OP's code is smaller, even though less portable, and other restrictions.  Else I suggest you query OP.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you convert the letters to numbers in your own way, surely there are standards which describe exactly this like for instance UTF-16, ASCII UTF-8, latin, latin-2 ... etc etc etc. If you are asking whether there are standard implemented in all languages, then probably the answer is yes. But if you are asking if the chars are in all the languages the same encoding then the answer is no do they provide sequential alphabet representation... I doubt it.

If you want to be comparing the numbers corresponding between standards then there are conversion libraries from one standard to another.

Comment: I would like to do that for instance when counting frequencies of letters in a text.

Comment: So why do you worry about the other programming languages?

Comment: Because it is more habit-related question rather than one-time solution related.